# SQLite Database Browser fails to open Firefox cookie database

Tags: firefox, cookies, sqlite

I downloaded [SQLite Database Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/files/latest/download) to preview cookies of Google Chrome and Firefox.

I could successfully preview Chrome's cookies, however cannot manage to preview Firefox cookies. I'm trying open this file `C:\Users\T3\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\mn0g2w2t.default\cookies.sqlite` but as a result get no error, just after opening it, SQLite Database Browser shows an empty database – but the file size is 1MB.

Does anyone have an idea what may be wrong?

Comment: I guess the same applies to bookmarks file `places.sqlite`? Read [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706537/firefox-locks-places-sqlite): FF uses exclusive lock. Try to copy the file somewhere else and see if this help (I can't test this and I'm cautious)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Firefox` keeps their database locked using [EXCLUSIVE locking model](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_locking_mode) so `SQLite Database Browser` cannot manage to open it, to preview data, one option is to copy DB file and open it from that place. Or even better option: open it programmicaly using SQLite library, this works always; copying just sometimes.

Comment: I have to regret myself. The newest [SQliteSpy 1.9.3](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/sqlitespy/index) is able to view places.sqlite and cookies.sqlite. I assume "SQLite Database Browser" should be able to this too, somehow.

Comment: newest version of SQLite Database Browser also works http://sqlitebrowser.org/

Answer (score -1):

[SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) is a Firefox extension but works with any sqlite db.